# Escaping gawk variables for shell commands

Tags: string, escape-characters, gawk

I'm trying to run a small gawk script which will run certain shell commands using `system()`. I want to get the file list with `find` and run the script like that:

```
find <arguments> -printf "%f\n" | script.awk
```

The problem is that these files have special characters such as spaces, quotes and parentheses in them. For example:

```
$ ls
'Aujourd'\''hui C'\''est Toi (Orchestral).flac'
```

I tried all sorts of quotes like the following:

```
system("<command> \""$0"\"")
```

And this:

```
system("<command> \'"$0"\'")
```

I get all sorts of errors, some of these errors are from `sh -c` and some are from `gawk`...

Is there a way to pass the record `$0` or any other variables from the gawk script to a shell command with out encountering all of theses problems?

**Note:** I know it could have been easier to just rename the files temporarily but I find it more challenging to avoid it.

### EDIT:

None of the suggested answers solved my problem so here is a more specific description of the problem: I'm trying to run a command which uses **2** awk variables. Examples:

If I run:

```
system("metaflac --show-tag=ARTIST \""FILE"\"")
```

I don't get an error because I quote `FILE` and because it doesn't contain double quotes it goes OK.

But if I run:

```
system("metaflac --set-tag=ARTIST="AWK_VAR_WITH_ARTIST_VALUE" "\"FILE\")
```

Even when I quote it, I get an error by `metaflac` that the flac file was not found. When reading the error message, I see the file name was split into separate words.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `system("<command> \"$0\"")` by awk's ability to write to a process, i.e. `print $0 | "pre;<command> \"$v\""`, where the *pre* part would read stdin into shell variable v. In bash this would be `read -r v`. You end up with this for example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ cmd="read -r v; ls -ld \"$v\"" }
     { print $0 | cmd; close(cmd); }'
```

If you want to handle horrible things like newlines in the filenames, you can go the print0 route in your find and, if your awk accepts `RS='\0'`, you have for bash:

```
find . -print0 |
awk -v RS='\0' '
 BEGIN{ cmd="read -r -d \"\" v; ls -ld \"$v\"" }
 { print $0 "\x00" | cmd; close(cmd); }'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case of spaces and single quotes, it should be sufficient to wrap the string in double quotes:

```
$ find -name 'Aujour*' -printf "%f\n" | awk '{system("ls -l \""$0"\"")}'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 May 26 11:27 Aujourd'hui C'est Toi (Orchestral).flac
```

Alternatively, if your shell provides a shell-quote format specifier you could consider using that in place of `find`'s internal `-printf`:

```
$ find -name 'Aujour*' -exec printf '%q\n' {} \; | awk '{system("ls -l "$0)}'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 May 26 11:27 ./Aujourd'hui C'est Toi (Orchestral).flac
```

From `help printf` in `bash` for example:

```
%q  quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
```

Comment: Wrapping the string in quotes doesn't work if the string contains one of these quote characters (or a bunch of other characters, for double quotes). Passing a pre-shell-quoted name to awk doesn't work if awk also needs to use the file name.